# Trying to write a simple app to allow user to drag a image

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to write an app to allow a person to drag around an image of the earth.

The method `touchesmoved` gets called when the user begins to drag his feet, but `[[ event allTouches] anyObject]` never returns the `earth` object, so it never gets dragged,

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch=[[ event allTouches] anyObject];

    if ( [touch view] == earth )
    {
        CGPoint location = [ touch locationInView: self.view];
        earth.center=location;          
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using `[ event allTouches]` instead of `touches`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for get touch use `UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];`

Change your `touchesMoved:` like:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

    UITouch *touch=[ touches anyObject];

    if ( [touch view] == earth )
    {
        CGPoint location = [ touch locationInView: self.view];
        earth.center=location;          
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,Stil did not work, I ended up getting earth's rec, then ssing a if then to see if location is inside